# SAQL computeExpression with date_diff() or daysBetween() and values that may be null

Tags: analytics, saql, dataflow

I have a dataflow with a computeExpression step where I want to define the number of days between two datetime fields.

The SAQL expression below executes correctly, however in instances where my records *haven't* been submitted for approval, `Submitted_for_Approval_DateTime__c_sec_epoch` is equal to 0, which causes `date_diff` to return the number of days between January 1st 1970 and the CreatedDate (as of the current day, this is -18,741).

[image: Computed Field]

How do I modify the following expression to output a blank or null value when `Submitted_for_Approval_DateTime__c` is null?

```
date_diff("day", toDate(CreatedDate_sec_epoch), toDate(Submitted_for_Approval_DateTime__c_sec_epoch))
```

Similarly, I also have this expression which has the same issue. Only in this instance both values may be null, resulting in a misleading 0 days value (i.e. the number of days between January 1 1970 and January 1 1970).

```
daysBetween(toDate(Submitted_for_Approval_DateTime__c_sec_epoch), toDate(Approved_DateTime__c_sec_epoch))
```